# Making an RPG in Python

Tags: python

The code gets stuck within the yes_or_no function right after the user input. No error message, please help! As you can see all I am trying to do is effectuate a simple purchase, I haven't been able to test the buy_something function, and I'm aware that it may have issues.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

# Intro
print "Input Name:"
time.sleep(1)
name = raw_input()
print "Welcome to Tittyland brave %s'" %(name)
time.sleep(2)
print "You are given nothing but 500 gold to start you journey..."
time.sleep(2)
print "Good luck..."
time.sleep(3)
print "Shopkeeper: 'Eh there stranger! Looks like you'll need some gear before going into the wild! Check out my store!'"
time.sleep(4)
print ""

#Inventory and first shop
inventory = {
    'pocket' : [],
    'backpack' : [],
    'gold' : 500,
}

shop = {
    'dagger' : 50,
    'leather armor' : 150,
    'broadsword' : 200,
    'health potion' : 75,   
}

#Buying items
for key in shop:
    print key
    print "price: %s" % shop[key]
    print ""
print "Shopkeeper: So, you interested in anything?"

answer1 = raw_input()
item = raw_input()

def buying_something(x):
    for i in shop:
        if shop[i] == x:
            inventory[gold] -= shop[i]
            inventory[backpack].append(shop[i])

def yes_or_no(x):   
    if x == 'yes':
        print "Shopkeeper: 'Great! So what is your desire stranger"
        buying_something(item)
    else:
        print "Shopkeeper: 'Another time then'"


yes_or_no(answer1)
```

Comment: "Welcome to Tittyland," eh? Anyway you're reading two lines of input consecutively. It doesn't get stuck, it just waits for the second line.

Comment: As a rule -- reproducers should consist of only the minimal code needed to demonstrate a problem. In this case, that would be something like two lines, rather than your whole program -- which is to say, *only* the place where it gets stuck. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed both your functions. You had your `raw_inputs` at the wrong place:

```
def yes_or_no(purchase_q):
    if purchase_q == "yes":
        while True:
            things = raw_input("Great. What is your hearts desire(type no more to exit shop): ")
            if things != "no more":
                buying_something(things)
            else:
                print "Good luck on your journey then"
                break


def buying_something(item):
    if item in shop.keys():
        print "You have %s gold available" %(inventory.get('gold'))
        print "Item Added {0}: ".format(item)
        backpack_items = inventory.get('backpack')
        backpack_items.append(item)
        item_cost = shop.get(item)
        print "Cost of Item is %s gold coins " %(item_cost)
        inventory['gold'] = shop.get(item) - item_cost
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that after this line:

```
print "Shopkeeper: So, you interested in anything?"
```

you wait for raw input with this `answer1 = raw_input()`
Then immediately after you type yes or no, you wait for input again `item = raw_input()`

Tt's not getting stuck or anything, it's just doing as it's told.

```
print "Shopkeeper: So, you interested in anything?"

answer1 = raw_input()
item = raw_input() // <-- This is in the wrong place
yes_or_no(answer1)
```

What you've written requires the user to type in the item they want after the yes or no answer, and regardless of a yes or no. I suggest you move the `item = raw_input()` into your yes_or_no function.

```
def yes_or_no(x):   
    if x == 'yes':
        print "Shopkeeper: 'Great! So what is your desire stranger"
        item = raw_input()
        buying_something(item)
    else:
        print "Shopkeeper: 'Another time then'"
```